# 52 is not a valid value for \Name\

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to show an angle in my program but I can't find a way to get the number from my xaml.cs to my xaml file without x:name. Name is restricted.

My xaml code :

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Angle1" Margin="468,580,749,62" />
```

My cs code :

```
Vector3D SL = Vector3D.Subtract(EL, SC);
Vector3D SR = Vector3D.Subtract(ER, SC);
Vector3D SS = Vector3D.Subtract(SP, SC);

double LAngSR_SS = Vector3D.AngleBetween(SR, SS); //Angle 
double LAngSL_SS = Vector3D.AngleBetween(SL, SS); //Angle

double LAngSR_SSround = Math.Round(LAngSR_SS, 1, MidpointRounding.ToEven); 
double LAngSL_SSround = Math.Round(LAngSL_SS, 1, MidpointRounding.ToEven);

string Angle1 = LAngSR_SSround.ToString(); //double to string
string Angle2 = LAngSL_SSround.ToString(); //double to string

TextBlock Angletext = new TextBlock();
Angletext.Name = Angle1;
```

Is there an alternative for name or some other way?

Comment: Names cannot begin with a numeric character. Why are you assigning that value to `.Name` anyway? I'm not clear on what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Do you want to add text to the textblock?

Comment: I'm with @DanPuzey, bit confused as to what you're trying to do. If you're wanting to display the angle within the textblock defined in your xaml - just use `Angle1.text = MyAngleValue` You will have to change the name of your `string Angle1` though, as it matches your textblocks name

Comment: Yes but i wanted to add numbers (angles) . What is not possible. So i was looking for another way but was not able to find one. So i was asking here

Comment: Yes you can have numbers in the `.Text` property. `.Name` is the actual name of your control, not for storing data.

Comment: ahh okay sorry i was not able to see that for hours.. I was totally thinking the wrong way. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Text** Property instead of **Name** Property of textblock.